# Creating dynamic ng-model for dynamic rows in table and get values and put in API

Tags: angularjs

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK9qE.png)

```
  <tr>       
    <td>{{transDept}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="x in Sales">
    <select ng-model="ddl[transDept.AccountCode]"   onchange="changeSelectedOptionText(this)"  style="width:100px;">
      <option value=""> </option>
      <option  ng-selected="trans.AccountCode == {{x}}.{{transDept}}"  ng-repeat="trans in CatogoriesAccountdatas" value="{{trans.AccountCode}}">{{trans.AccountCode}}| {{trans.Name}} </option>
      </select>
    </td>       
  </tr>
```

{"Action":"PostConfigurationData.accountsetting","ConfigurationFilter":{"CompanyID":0,"username":null,"Password":null,"UserId":0},"ConfigurationData":"[{\"CompanyID\":"+COMPANYID+",\"EntityID\":"+$scope.LOGINENTITYID+",\"Department\":\"BENDIGO\",\"Accounts\":\"{\\"Material\\":200,\\"Labour\\":090,\\"General\\":445,\\"Freight\\":970,\\"Fees\\":300,\\"Rounding\\":970}\"}]"},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could something like this, that keeps track of the selected elements in an array from each row. you could enhance this further as per your requirement, but I hope this would be a good staring point for you to solve.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.dataSelected = [];
    $scope.dropdownValuesCollection = [{
      name: "One",
      data: [{
        name: 'Name',
        value: '123'
      }, {
        name: 'Name-1',
        value: '123-1'
      }, {
        name: 'Name-2',
        value: '123-2'
      }]
    }, {
      name: "Two",
      data: [{
        name: 'Name',
        value: '123'
      }, {
        name: 'Name-1',
        value: '123-1'
      }, {
        name: 'Name-2',
        value: '123-2'
      }]
    }, ];
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="dropdownValues in dropdownValuesCollection track by $index" ng-init="dataSelected[$index].company = dropdownValues.name">
        <td>
          {{dropdownValues.name}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <select ng-model="dataSelected[$index].dropdownValue">
            <option ng-repeat="item in dropdownValues.data" ng-value="dropdownValues.name +'-'+ item.value">{{dropdownValues.name +"-"+ item.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    Selected Values : {{dataSelected}}

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your active reply but i still have one question that what  variable should i put on my api on behalf of department and account

Comment: I don't understand, can you be a little more specific please.Which department and account you are talking about

Comment: what is the source for the dynamic value you are talking about? is that in your table row data?

Comment: Yes im loading dynamic column in which im loading Department like BENDIGO , LICENSES , MAINTENANCE on that basis im creating the row in which im get dropdown option so whatever comes in my table heading that value should be dynamic

Comment: in that case, you could use ng-init on row init to populate the value. updated the code snippet for reference.

Comment: No but its ok buddy may be requirement is not clear on chat, but i really appreciate your effort

Comment: A value from a variable on row is not something you need? if it is not from the td repeat, you could just populate it from the scope directly. instead of reading it from the loop variable

Comment: Do you have any skype ID or i can share the zoom link over there i can share my requirement may it will be easy to resolve there..

Comment: i do have a zoom  if you want to go over

Comment: please join this link

Comment: you could give this a shot <tbody ng-repeat ="transDept in transactionDeptData track by $index " ng-init="ddl[$index].transDept = transDept" >

    <tr>
    <td>{{transDept}}</td>
<td ng-repeat="x in Sales">
    <select ng-model="ddl[$index].x"  style="width:100px;">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option  ng-selected="trans.AccountCode == {{x}}.{{transDept}}"  ng-repeat="trans in CatogoriesAccountdatas" value="{{trans.AccountCode}}">{{trans.AccountCode}}| {{trans.Name}} </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>